# Image slider in ember

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using "ember-cli-slick": "2.0.0"
And in handlebars I am using this component -

```
{{#each model as |image index|}}
    {{#slick-slider autoplay=true arrows=false}}
        <img src="{{image.url}}">
    {{/slick-slider}}
{{/each}}
```

When i am inspect elements i can see images with width 1px and height 0px.

Can anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The slick slider expects to have a list of images in the component block.
You can see more examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-slick)

```
{{#slick-slider autoplay=true arrows=false}}    
  {{#each model as |image index|}}    
    <div class="box"><img src="{{image.url}}"></div>
  {{/slick-slider}}
{{/each}}
```